# Making a script that can recover a corrupt serialized string that have serialized string in PHP

Tags: php, serialization, string-length

My string like this

$a='a:6:{s:12:"measurements";s:9:"100x100cm";s:11:"composition";s:80:"a:2:{s:2:"en";s:18:"50%Linen 50%Cotton";s:2:"de";s:22:"50%Leinen 50%Baumwolle";}";s:11:**"base_colour";s:71**:"a:2:{s:2:"en";s:16:"017 - Pure white";s:2:"de";**s:15:"017 - Reinweiß"**;}";s:12:"fabric_group";s:0:"";s:14:"package_amount";s:1:"1";s:10:"min_amount";s:1:"4";}';

```
base_colour";s:71 must be 70
s:15:"017 - Reinweiß";must be 14
```

All scripts on stackoverflow  not working

Comment: Please try to be more clear. What do you mean by "All scripts on stackoverflow not working"?

Answer (score 0):

This works;

```
function mb_unserialize($string) {
    $string = mb_convert_encoding($string, "UTF-8", mb_detect_encoding($string, "UTF-8, ISO-8859-1, ISO-8859-15", true));
    return unserialize($string);
}
```